# Mongoose Post Middleware Testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, express, mongoose

I have two mongoose models.  **Page** and **Thumbnail**

```
  var Page = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, default: '', trim: true },
    url:   { type: String, default: '', trim: true },
    thumbnails: {type: Schema.ObjectId,  ref: 'Thumbnails'},
  });

  Page.post('save', function(doc) {
   if(doc.thumbnails) return;
   Thumbnail.generate(doc.url, function(err, thumb){
     doc.thumbnails = thumb;
     doc.save()
   });
  });

 var Thumbnail = new Schema({
    domain: {type: String, trim: true},
    url: {
      small: { type: String, trim: true },
      original: {type: String, trim: true }
    }
 });

 Thumbnail.statics.generate = function(doc, cb) {
   // generate site preview , save the thumbnail and call cb
 }
```

and I'm using mongoose post middleware to generate the thumbnails.
How can I test that in the Post middleware the **Thumbnail.generate** is called or not called?

Thanks

Comment: Just move middleware function to a module so that you can require it in test and then test it alone. p.s. I bet it will throw `cannot read property generate of undefined` error. Add `var Thumbnail = connection.model('Thumbnail');` before you use it.

Comment: hi @EugeneKostrikov, so your idea is expose the post functions and override that functions, right ? could you write just your idea, without worrying about syntax or other errors. What I really want understand is the ideia. How could you change this gist ?
https://gist.github.com/tdantas/9bab48899c9123dca0e5

Comment: Sure, here it is https://gist.github.com/EugeneKostrikov/7775621b69ee6d9c7b1e  The only logic you have in the middleware is to decide if you need to create thumbs. So you can simply mock out the doc you test against and feed the middleware with well known parameters.

Comment: Thanks, @EugeneKostrikov. extracting and mocking with javascript/nodejs is the best way to test inner functions. What I did was exporting the inner functions to be stubbed in the test environment. Thanks